# Unable to locate elements even by using correct xpath in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate an `element(tabs)` on a webpage using its `xpath` but instead of locating it, the code is selecting the `tab` just above it. Xpath used is absolute. Please suggest on this, anyone.
Following is the code snippet:

```
WebElement table=(new WebDriverWait(driver,200)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//tagname[@title='value']")));
Thread.sleep(500);
table.click();
```

`tabs` in this context,basically are webpage titles arranged one below the other in form of tabs,one can access these webpages on clicking on these `tabs`.

Comment: can you provide us with the HTML of the part of the page you're checking?

Comment: I second what Klendathu said.  We need the HTML.

Comment: Try to avoid using the Thread.Sleep method.  The WebDriverWait is already waiting for the element to appear - no need for the Sleep.